# Jersey SEVERE: Servlet load() Exception

Tags: macos, web-services, rest, jersey

I have made one project using Rest Web Service. In my Windows PC works fine but I needed to put it on MAC machine (using OS X 10.8.1) and there when I execute it gives me this exception:

```
SEVERE: Servlet /pt.Agile21.Acerola.WebService threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
```

Exists some difference relevant between Windows and MAC ??
I have configured TomCat on MAC, if I strat the tomcat on terminal it goes to the localhost:8080 without problems too! SO I think the problem is on eclipse right?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you dont have required jar files.In order to run jersey application you need jersey-server.jar as well as jersey-core.jar files in your application lib folder.

Comment: Yes.. I put all the jars in the Lib file on the WebContent !